# How do I activate another Enumerator inside the first one

Tags: c#, iterator, enumerable, yield-return

I have two separate actions that are enumerators.

One can be run independently, the other depends on the first to run afterwards.

I though I would be really smart by doing this:

```
public IEnumerator<IResult> DoStuffIndependently()
{
   yield return this;
   yield return that;
}

public IEnumerator<IResult> DoStuffBeforeSometimes()
{
   yield return AffectThis;
   yield return AffectThat;

   yield return DoStuffIndependently();
}
```

This doesn't work, also putting it through a foreach doesn't work either. I don't want to step through everything myself and I'm guessing there is a really easy way to do this.

Comment: Why does putting it through a foreach not work?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Do you actually yeild "this" or can "this" be replaced with "foobar"?

Comment: @DanPuzey does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @vidstige Yes absolutely, didn't think about this as a keyword when I wrote it.

Comment: Ok to be a little bit of an asshole, I didn't tell the whole story to begin with. I'm using Caliburn Micro IResult thingy to do coroutines. I doubt it's relevant, but who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be IEnumerator and not IEnumerable, you'll have to iterate through it manually:

```
public IEnumerator<IResult> DoStuffIndependently() {
    yield return this;
    yield return that;
}

public IEnumerator<IResult> DoStuffBeforeSometimes() {
    yield return AffectThis;
    yield return AffectThat;

    var dsi = DoStuffIndependently();
    while (dsi.MoveNext()) yield return dsi.Current;
}
```

Comment: pedantic point: you should always check to dispose an iterator. Fortunately this is easy with the generic version, since `IDisposable` is guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

A method is *either* an iterator block (`yield return` etc), **xor** a regular method (`return` etc). It cannot be both. As such, to use another iterator, you must iterate it - i.e.

```
yield return AffectThis;
yield return AffectThat;
using(var iter = DoStuffIndependently()) {
    while(iter.MoveNext()) yield return iter.Current;
}
```

Alternatively, you could perhaps use `Concat` to stitch together two *existing* iterators.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic thanks, will correct; I assumed it was IEnumerable

Comment: `Concat()` doesn't work on `IEnumerator`s, so the alternative solution wouldn't work.

Comment: @svick if a person was doing lots of work *specifically with ienumerator* (rather than ienumerable), it would be fairly trivial to *add* a Concat extension method for iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerator` and the `foreach` should work fine:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> DoStuffIndependently()
{
   yield return This;
   yield return That;
}

public IEnumerable<IResult> DoStuffBeforeSometimes()
{
   yield return AffectThis;
   yield return AffectThat;
   foreach (var x in DoStuffIndependently())
        yield return x;
}
```

Alternatively, call [IEnumerator.MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) explicitly, as [Marc suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540168/533120).